# How to select and choose a ImageView from a toolbar with one touch/click event?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have a bar layout with four ImageViews.

The code is showed below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contact2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_phone_state" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contact_call"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/contactcall_state" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contact_call2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_phone_state" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_bar_trigger"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/contact_phone_state" />

</LinearLayout>
```

At first the ImageView(contact_bar_trigger) would be showed on the screen only,

after touch(keep action_down) it, the LinearLayout(contact_bar_layout) will show up,

and the problem comes, is it possible to choose one ImageView from contact_bar by the touch motionevent action_up?

if not, please give me some suggestion to implement this. Thank you~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem but, if I've good understood what you're excepting, you'd like to select a picture from your layout (with the 3 ImageView ; called contact_bar_layout) by a motionevent action_up.

To do it, you have to use code (and not just XML) and for each ImageView, you add a listener for each of them (you can use a method for all or do it separately). Then in each listener, you define what you want to do when this motionevent action_up is done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry for the poor description...actually what i am trying to do is use one touch listener to control pick and select functions...while touching(action_down) trigger, the toor bar will pop out, after that moving to the expected button from tool bar, and using "action_up" to select the function of button~